# Delay between iterated elements and on subscribe

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

FIXED to yield the desired output!

I have a list of items that I need to iterate and between each element I would like to wait 2 seconds. when all items are processed and subscribe is called then I would like to wait another 2 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
rx.Observable.from(new String[] {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"})
        .zipWith(rx.Observable.interval(2000, 1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a,b) -> a)
        .subscribe(name -> {
            System.out.println(name);
        }, e -> {
            System.out.println("ERROR" + e);
        }, () -> {
            rx.Observable.timer(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                         .subscribe(notUsed -> "THE END!");
        });


        try {
            // Sleep so the program doesn't exit immediately
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

It runs pretty nice, but when it performs the 'interval' in the subscribe it prints "THE END!" three times !

```
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4
THE END!
THE END!
THE END!
```

Any idea how to improve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your first stream (Test1-4) is completed, you can concat it with `Observable` emitting single value after delay `Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(notUsed -> "The end")`

Copy pastable code

```
rx.Observable.from(new String[]{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"})
                .zipWith(rx.Observable.interval(2000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a, b) -> a)
                .concatWith(Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(notUsed -> "The end"))
                .subscribe(name -> {
                            System.out.println(name);
                        }, e -> {
                            System.out.println("ERROR" + e);
                        }
                );


        try {
            // Sleep so the program doesn't exit immediately
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: How can I change the above code so the .map(..) would call a method that returns void (and not String) and must be called only after all items in the array were emitted?

Comment: Is it possible to put a 'interval' call at the complete part of subscribe?

Comment: instead of `.concatWith()` you can add `doOnCompleted(() -> Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doOnCompleted(this::voidFunc).subscribe())`

Comment: Nice! - Look at my last edit (I edited the original post) I think it's readable and uses minimum amount of RX calls.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does exactly what you tell it to do :-)

```
 time   event
-------------------------------------
    0   start, wait 2000 ms initially
 2000   emit "Test1", wait 1000 ms
 3000   emit "Test2", wait 1000 ms
 4000   emit "Test3", wait 1000 ms
 5000   emit "Test4", emit the OnCompleted event, wait 2000 ms
 7000   print "THE END!", wait 1000 ms
 8000   print "THE END!", wait 1000 ms
 9000   print "THE END!", wait 1000 ms
10000   main thread dies
```

I don't know exactly what you want, but I presume you want to have just a single "THE END!". If you want to have this to be delayed by 1000 ms as well, you have to do the following:

```
Observable.from(new String[] {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"})
    .zipWith(Observable.interval(2000, 1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a,b) -> a)
    .concatWith(Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ignoreElements())
    .subscribe(
        System.out::println,
        e -> System.out.println("ERROR" + e),
        () -> System.out.println("THE END!));
```

If you don't want the delay at the end, just remove the `concat` above.

What this `concat` does is it waits for the first sequence (`from` and `zip`) to complete and subscribe to the `Observer` once the `OnCompleted` from the first sequence is emitted. Once the second sequence is subscribed, it waits 1000 ms, emits an element and completes (because it is a `timer` rather than an `interval`). Because you ignore the elements (a.k.a. the `OnNext`s) you are only left with the `OnCompleted` event, which triggers the callback in the `subscribe`.

Comment: I will try to run your solution - it seems like it ignores the array elements - but I need them to be processed at the subscribe part.

Comment: No, it only ignores the element from `Observable.timer(...)` AFAIK. Haven't tested it though :-) Note that the `ignoreElements` is inside the `concat`!

Comment: you mean `Observable.timer` and `Observable.interval`, right? Yes, they run on different/new threads, by default coming from a `ComputationScheduler`. See also [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#interval(long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). There are overloads of these methods that give you the option to provide your own scheduler rather than the defaults.